# How to load test asynchronous services (aws)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, load-testing, gatling, artillery

I want to load test a StepFunction (aws) with load testing tools like Gatling or Artillery...
The problem is when I want to load test this stepfunction I make a request to StartExecution to execute the stepfunction but the stepfunction returns immediately an http response even if the it is processing : because it's async.

Then how can I test my stepFunction ??

Thanks !

Comment: What is the data you want go get from the load test? is Gatling or Artillery required or maybe not?

Comment: I want to get the time execution of my services inside the stepfunction. Gatling or Artillery are not required.

Comment: You can just fire and forget the step function. Say, 10K concurrent and wait. Later, you can pull the data directly from CloudWatch ActivityRunTime and get the measurement you want for each step https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/procedure-cw-metrics.html